# how to set temporary environment variable windows command prompt like bash?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

In Bash I can create **TEMPORARY** environment variables on a command line. For eample

```
DEBUG=foo somecommand
```

This sets the environmnet variable `DEBUG` but only for `somecommand`. When the line is finished `DEBUG` is no longer set.

Can I do something similar in the Windows Command Processor?

Note: Using `SET` does not work. That sets the current command processors environment, not the just for the command about to be executed.

To give another example here's a small node.js program that prints the value
of a single environment variable

```
// test.js
console.log(`${process.argv[2]}='${process.env[process.argv[2]]}'`);
```

Let's run it in bash

```
$ export FOO=abc
$ node test.js FOO
FOO='abc'
```

Then let's run it with a temporary setting

```
$ FOO=def node test.js FOO
FOO='def'
```

Check that FOO is still abc

```
$ echo $FOO
abc
```

How I can accomplish the same thing in the Windows command prompt?

One way seems to be to relaunch the command processor as in

```
cmd /S /C "set "FOO=def" & node test.js FOO"
```

Is there another way or is that it?

Comment: "Is there another way or is that it?" I think that is the only way. `set foo=bar && echo %foo% && set foo= && echo %foo%` does not work :(

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `set` command:

```
C:\>set foo=bar

C:\>echo %foo%
bar

C:\>exit
```

*Open cmd again*

```
C:\>echo %foo%
%foo%

C:\>
```

Comment: why do i keep getting notifications for this?

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking. In Linux you can set the value of an environment variable for the executed command only. It can be an environment valiable that exists and it doesn't get overriden for other processes. With `set`, you change the value of the environment variable FOR ALL processes in that session.